# Manipulating image size with css failed to keep the original y position..!

Tags: jquery, css, image, coordinates, scale

I'm using jQuery to create interactive graphic.. I have a jslider and I want to change size of images when value of the slider changes. It is actually working like this:

```
 <script>
        jQuery("#SliderSingle2").slider({ from: 2002, to: 2012, step: 1, round: 0,     skin: "round", limits: false, format: { format: '##', locale: 'de' }, scale: ['2002', '2003', '2004', '2005', '2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012'],callback: function( value ){
                var SliderValue = $('#SliderSingle2').attr('value');
                if(value== "2003"){
                    $("#img").css("transform","scale(0.9)");
                                            $("#img2").css("transform","scale(1.0)");
                    $("#img3").css("transform","scale(0.7)");
                }else if(value=="2004"){
                        $("#img1").css("transform","scale(1.0)");
                        $("#img2").css("transform","scale(1.0)");
                                            $("#img3").css("transform","scale(0.7)");
}}};
</script>
```

.. Images do grow when I change the value of the slider.. The problem is that I want those images to keep their position in the Y-axis, those can not grow downwards, images should be on same level/height on the page all the time.. because those pictures cover the slider otherwise. I don't have a clue how to do so..?Anyone vicer..?

-EDIT-
Those values how much to grow are going to be proportional with the data of that year.. I'm trying to draw that data so it would make more effect, when you "can see the growth/data change"..

Comment: Could you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: I don't know is it possible to try this with jsfiddle because I have downloaded the jslider and I have these images on my computer..? I'm quite new with javascript..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/v3gUg/18/ Theres an example of jslider in jsfiddle. Just use some random pictures from the internet.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/QNLMN/17/ ..if I did that one right.. Just want those pictures to keep their position.. If I change the scaling I still want those pictures to be in line with each other.. above the slider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just give the images vertical-align: bottom.

```
img {
   vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Then they should stay in line.

**EDIT:**

I think this is what you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/gLRck/

Instead of using transform scale we just set the height. I also made the images resize on dragging the handles instead of when releasing mousebutton.

**EDIT EDIT:**
And now it also works in chrome ;)

Comment: Then you are not doing it right. If you make your jsfiddle work i can easily show you, but else i have no clue whats going on.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/someProgress/QNLMN/42/ I tried it like this.. I tried both.. vertical-align: bottom and middle.. Still pictures will loose the positioning and won't stay in line. Any succestions?

Comment: Your images are not resizing when i pull the handles

Comment: Don't know what is going on.. I just checked that jsfiddle and it was working..?

Comment: Ok i see, its the css scaling that messes it up, and also it doesn't work in chrome. But i'll make a fiddle and show you how you can do it. 2 minutes

Comment: Do you have any clue, what could I do to arrenge them by which one is the biggest and so on..?